# a More Active(prompting) GUFW

Tags: networking, firewall

Excuse me Please:

I am currently in the process of installing/configuring Ubuntu 16.x, and will be installing GUFW.
I would prefer to avoid passive applications, and would that the "firewall" installed be more "active" and prompt when any application attempts to connect with the network, to then give authorization or denial of said access.

As an additional plus to said application, I would that said firewall also prevent program A from launching program B on its own.

Any insight, advice, direction or instruction would be greatly appreciated.